# tabs + swipe trying to make a call from fragment 1 using imgbutton

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have set up an pp using the default tabs + swipe layout, i figured out how to display different content on different slides,

the problem im having is how i can start an intent (make a phone call using an imagebutton.

the image button is is fragment 1 or slide 1, i dont know where to declre the button, or how to format the code,

best i have managed is 1 error stating:

Gradle: error: non-static method findViewById(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

my code is as follows,

```
/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if ((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1)) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
            return view;

            ImageButton ib1;

            ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib1);

            // add button listener
            ib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0377778888"));
                    startActivity(callIntent);

                }

            });




        }

        if ((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2)) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test2, container, false);
            return view;
        }


        if ((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==3)) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test3, container, false);
            return view;
        }

            else {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return textView;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe remove the `static` in the `DummySectionFragment` declaration if this is not an inner class.
Also the findViewById should be `getView().findViewById`. Im no expert on `Fragment` but try this.

Comment: `if ((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==3)) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test3, container, false);
                ImageButton newPage = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ib1);
                newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:07********"));
                        startActivity(callIntent);` this was my solution